# MySQL Default value error in Windows and not in Linux when the value is not given for NOT- NULL field?

Tags: mysql

MySQL Default value error is thrown in Windows and not in Linux when the value is not given for NOT- NULL field?

ex: table a has a not-null column and when we insert in windows without the values for the column the row is not getting inserted where as in linux when we don't give any value or tag for the same, it gets saved successfully.

Can someone explain why?

Thanks,

Comment: There is some weird configuration setting in MySQL where NULL values are silently replaced with 0. Probably your two installations are configured differently.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the first comment, it seems a configuration problem. Checks particularly the variable [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode) `SELECT @@sql_mode;` and values [TRADITIONAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional) | [STRICT_ALL_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables) | [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables).